# iOS Swift memory leak when creating SceneKit objects in separate thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, scenekit

If you create a new Single View App, add a single UIButton, and give it this IBAction:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func trigger(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            for _ in 0..<100000 {
                SCNSphere(radius: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Those `SCNSphere` instances leak permanently, even though you're not even creating a reference to those instances. If you do this on the main thread it's fine, but any `SCNNode` or `SCNGeometry` instances you create on any thread other than the main thread will never be deallocated. Am I missing something here, is this expected behaviour, or is this a bug?

Comment: Try putting the loop inside a `autoreleasepool{}`.

Comment: I tried `autoreleasepool`, it didn't have any affect.